# Get attributes with missing product values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables. Products(Id, Name, ...), Attributes(Id, Name, ...),ProductsAttributesValues(Id, ProductId, AttributeId, Value). I am saving product attribute value in ProductsAttributesValues. Now I need to select all attributes that have missing product attribute value. I have tried this,

```
SELECT
    bp.Id AS BaseProductId,
    bp.Name AS BaseProductName,
    a.Id AS AttributeID,
    a.Name AS AttributeName,
    pav.Value
FROM Attributes a
CROSS JOIN BaseProducts bp
LEFT JOIN ProductsAttributesValues pav
    ON a.Id = pav.AttributeID AND bp.Id = pav.BaseProductId
WHERE pav.Id IS NULL
ORDER BY bp.Id
```

But it is taking too much time and not returning any result.

Comment: I should probably start with trying NOT EXISTS...

Answer (score 0):

So you need to get `Attributes` that have no value in `ProductsAttributesValues`, you can do it with `LEFT JOIN` but you need to change `CROSS JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` and you need to move the join after joining `ProductsAttributesValues`:

```
SELECT
    bp.Id AS BaseProductId,
    bp.Name AS BaseProductName,
    a.Id AS AttributeID,
    a.Name AS AttributeName,
    pav.Value
FROM Attributes a
LEFT JOIN ProductsAttributesValues pav
    ON a.Id = pav.AttributeID
LEFT JOIN BaseProducts ON bp.Id = pav.BaseProductId
WHERE pav.Value IS NULL
```

Comment: No I need products with no value

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for products that are missing any attribute (products that are in productattribute and missing some attributes + Products which are missing from productattributes altogether)

```
CREATE TABLE #products(tid INT )
INSERT INTO #products( tid )
VALUES  ( 1),(2),(3)
CREATE TABLE #attributes(aid INT )
INSERT INTO #attributes VALUES(1),(2)
CREATE TABLE #prodattributes(tid INT ,aid INT)
INSERT INTO #prodattributes VALUES(1,1),(1,2),(3,1)

SELECT * FROM #products
SELECT * FROM #attributes
SELECT * FROM #prodattributes 

SELECT * FROM  #products p CROSS JOIN #attributes #a 
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM #prodattributes
```